# Не получается вывести string значение из бд в toast при нажатии на элемент Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Пытаюсь сделать так, что бы при нажатии на элемент `listview` всплывало окно с названием столбца, но получается вывести только `id`, или, если использовать  `.getItemAtPosition(position)`, то получаю строку вида `android.database.sqlite.SQliteCursor@....`
Прошу помощи в решении.

Код класса.

```
public class StopActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView lvData;
    bd db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    TextView tvText;
   // CursorAdapter scAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_stop );

        // открываем подключение к БД
        db = new bd( this );
        db.open();

        // формируем столбцы сопоставления
        String[] from = new String[]{bd.COLUMN_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.tvText};

        // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0 );
        //scAdapter = new MyAdapter( this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0 );
        lvData = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.lvData );
        lvData.setAdapter( scAdapter );

        // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
        registerForContextMenu( lvData );

        // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader( 0, null, this );

        lvData.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Вы выбрали " + lvData.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        } );
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
        return new MyCursorLoader( this, db );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor( cursor );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    }


  static  class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        bd db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, bd db) {
            super( context );
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllDataStop();

            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep( 3 );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cursor;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что метод возвращает банально Cursor. Все, что тебе нужно, это получить нужный столбец:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) lvData.getAdapter().getItem(position);
String text = cursor.getString(0);
Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Вы выбрали " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

Еще можно у адаптера курсор получить и ходить по нему:

```
Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) lvData.getAdapter()).getCursor();
c.moveToPosition(position);
String text = c.getString(0);
Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Вы выбрали " + text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я немного поправил ваше решение, а то 1 метод выводил позицию, а во втором текст выводился только для последнего элемента. Изменив строку как написано ниже, все стало работать корректно.

String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(bd.COLUMN_NUMBER));

Comment: Наверное он не позицию выводил, а ID? Нужно знать номер, а getColumnIndexOrThrow возвращает как раз номер колонки по ее имени.